# ConTeXt: How to use xmlflush in lua?

Tags: context, xml

I tried to use context's xml with this xhtml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
  <q>Some quote with <em>italic</em> and a nested <q>quote</q></q>
</body>
</html>
```

with this environment file

```
\startxmlsetups xml:setup
    \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{*}{-}
    \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{html|body|q|em}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:setup}

\startxmlsetups xml:html
    \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:body
    \startdocument
        \xmlflush{#1}
    \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:q
    \quotation{\xmlflush{#1}}
    %\xmlfunction{#1}{q}
\stopxmlsetups
\startluacode
    function xml.functions.q(t)
        context.quotation(lxml.flush(t)) --does not work
    end
\stopluacode

\definebodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]
\startxmlsetups xml:em
    \dontleavehmode{\em \xmlflush{#1}}
\stopxmlsetups
```

This works if I use the TeX version. If I switch to the lua function it does not work anymore. Whats the lua equivalent of `\quotation{\xmlflush{#1}}`?

Comment: `context.quotation(lxml.flush(t))` cannot work you expect, because `lxml.flush(t)` does not return anything.  What is the reason why you want to do this at the Lua end?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I was trying to do this because its easier in lua to have conditionals cause I can use logical operators.

Comment: I have updated my answer after reading the ConTeXt Lua Documents manual. Very useful!

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `context.quotation(lxml.flush(t))` cannot work because `lxml.flush` does not yield a return value.  Why that is and what the consequences are is discussed below.

You have encountered the hen-egg problem of LuaTeX.  The fundamental question of which comes first, the Lua backend code or the typeset output.

The LuaTeX designers decided, that the Lua backend code comes first.  Therefore, there is no way to access text which is typeset using `tex.sprint` in the same Lua chunk (which is what `lxml.flush` does under the hood).  You first have to hand back to the TeX end before you process it.  In this case the solution is to simply do `\quotation{\xmlfunction{#1}{q}}`.

Taking a closer look we realize that when we call the function `quotation` the arguments are evaluated *before* the function is called.  That means that `lxml.flush(t)` happens before `quotation` even starts and the output has already been handed back to TeX.  That is why we need to defer the evaluation using a lambda function.

```lua
function xml.functions.q(t)
    context.quotation(function() lxml.flush(t) end)
end
```

You can find more such tricks in section 3 “More on functions” of the [ConTeXt Lua Documents manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf).

```
\startbuffer[test]
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
  <q>Some quote with <em>italic</em> and a nested <q>quote</q></q>
</body>
</html>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:setup
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{html|body|q|em}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:setup}

\startxmlsetups xml:html
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:body
  \startdocument
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:q
  \xmlfunction{#1}{q}
\stopxmlsetups
\startluacode
function xml.functions.q(t)
    context.quotation(function() lxml.flush(t) end)
end
\stopluacode

\definebodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]
\startxmlsetups xml:em
  \dontleavehmode{\em \xmlflush{#1}}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlprocessbuffer{test}{test}{}
```